# How to list only eixsting files in a git repo?

Tags: git, git-ls-tree

I used `sparse checkout` to clone subfolders and files from a repo, as the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository). Currently, I want to list the checked out files in my disk - not the full repo tree, only the existing files, is there any command can do this?

I know I can use `git ls-tree` command to list the whole files in the repo, but that's not I want, I just need to list the existing files in my current repo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "in my current repo"?

Comment: @evolutionxbox,it's just means in my repo or in my disk

Comment: Ok cool. In your mind, what’s the difference between “whole repo” and “current repo”?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, but I didn't mention "whole repo", I just mention "whole files in the repo", I mean all the files in the repo. Because I used sparse checkout to clone part of the repo to my local, currently I want to list the checked out files in my disk.

Comment: Of you’re just listing files, I’d use `tree`.